# Android, using Realm singleton in Application

Tags: android, realm

I'm new to Realm, I'm wondering whether it's good practice to just have one Realm instance in Application object, use it across all cases needed in the app, and only close it in `onDestroy` of the Application class.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest do not have instance at application level.Create instance whenever it is required to perform DB operation else close it.

Comment: That's not a good idea because Realms are thread local. They are also cached for every thread so you don't need to do anything :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with keeping the Realm on the UI thread open and not closing it (note there is no `OnDestroy` on `Application`)

However you should keep the following in mind:

1) Realm can handle the process getting killed just fine, which means that forgetting to close Realm is not dangerous to your data.

2) Not closing Realm when the app goes in the background means you will be more likely to get killed by the system if it gets low on resources.

As Emanuele said. Realm use thread local caches internally in order to not open more Realms than needed. This means that you shouldn't care how many times you call `Realm.getInstance()` as in most cases it will just be a cache lookup. It is however good practise to always have a corresponding `close` method as well.

```
// This is a good pattern as it will ensure that the Realm isn't closed when
// switching between activities, but will be closed when putting the app in 
// the background.
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      realm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Christian Melchior The app goes into the background in onStop() not onDestroy(), and also, onDestroy() may never get called.  So wouldn't it be better to call realm.close() in onStop() ?