# Proper way to kill all the open connections in Realm

Tags: android, realm

It is very difficult to find where the connection is open. Is there any way I can force kill all the open connections to realm ?

Comment: Don't know why this question was downgraded, it's quite valid. It's as if Realm DB, by its design, is forcing a specific app design as well as business logic on the application. Rather unfortunate and quite frustrating at times. I just wish the example link provided in the answer below were more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. You will need to close the Realm on all threads you have open. Note that Realm uses a internal cache that is reference counted, so every call to getInstance() has to be matched by a close() call in order to fully close the Realm.

You can see this answer for a good pattern on how to achieve this: [Android, using Realm singleton in Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800031/android-using-realm-singleton-in-application/31803554#31803554)